# Subtract an input from the current number

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I've set up a [GitHub](https://github.com/the4dpatrick/macros-tracker) for my project plus a [GitHub page](http://the4dpatrick.github.io/macros-tracker/). It takes a set value and subtracts the input once the button is pushed.

The script should take in the value set initially as a variable subtract. Another variable current is defined as the current number. A newVal is defined as current - subtract. change the current value to the newVal. Before changing the number use the jQuery bounce effect.

At the moment the effect affects all of the numbers instead of the one that is edited.

This is what I've come up with until I got stuck
index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Macros Tracker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery.jeditable.mini.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Track your Macros</h1>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="calories">
            <div class="number"><p>1945</p></div>
            <div class="label"><p>Calories</p></div>
            <input type="text" id="subtract"></input>
            <button>Subtract</button>
        </div>
        <div id="protein">
            <div class="number"><p>200</p></div>
            <div class="label"><p>Protein</p></div>
            <input type="text"></input>
            <button>Subtract</button>
        </div>
        <div id="carbs">
            <div class="number"><p>150</p></div>
            <div class="label"><p>Carbs</p></div>
            <input type="text"></input>
            <button>Subtract</button>
        </div>
        <div id="fats">
            <div class="number"><p>51</p></div>
            <div class="label"><p>Fats</p></div>
            <input type="text"></input>
            <button>Subtract</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        var subtract = parseInt($('#subtract').val(), 10);
        var current = parseInt($('.number p').val());
        var newVal = current - subtract; 
        $('.number p').effect('explode');
        $('.number p').html(newVal);
    });
});
```

Comment: Make sure you continue to use the second parameter with `parseInt` - you did the first time, but not the second. And `<p>` elements don't have a `value` property (retrieved by `.val()`). You probably meant to use `.text()`

Comment: using `$('class here')` will return multiple elements, and requesting it's `val()` or `text()` will only return the value of the first element in the collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('.number p').html(newVal);` sets the html of all elements matching `.number p` to the specified html.

You need to use the context of the button and traverse the DOM to get the relevant elements:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        var $button = $(this);
        var subtract = parseInt($button.siblings('input').val(), 10);
        var $currentP = $button.siblings('.number').children('p');
        var current = parseInt($currentP.text(), 10);
        var newVal = current - subtract; 
        $currentP.effect('explode', function() {
            $currentP.text(newVal);
            $(this).show(); 
        });            
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks it seems to work, but the <p> has styling like style="visibility: visible; display: none; for some reason. Do I need to add more to the script to disable these defaults?

Comment: you code not work due to  $currentP.effect('explode'); Numbers disappear remove it

Comment: I edited my answer. I haven't tested it, but it looks like the explode effect hides the element. I added a callback to show the element after the animation completes.

Comment: I made another slight change that might look nicer for the user: the text doesn't update until the explode effect has finished.

Answer (score -1):

http://jsfiddle.net/zunc8/

You have to find just the one you want to change:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        var parent = $(this).parent();
        var subtract = parseInt(parent.find('#subtract').val(), 10);
        var current = parseInt(parent.find('.number p').text(),10);
        var newVal = current - subtract; 
        //$('.number p').effect('explode');
        parent.find('.number p').text(newVal);
    });
});
```